# SSIS 2005 export to xls remove header rows

Tags: ssis, export, xls

I am using SSIS to export data to xls.

I created a xls destination in a data flow with the following "CREATE TABLE `excel-destination` (`A` LongText `B` Long)"

In the connection manager when I set the "FirstRowHasColumnName" setting to False I get and error that Column A can not be found in the data source.

I don't want the Header columns in xls. Is there a way to remove them? or how should I create the xls destination not to show the column headers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you export to a flat-file destination this will export without columns in the first line. Set the delimiter to ',' and the extension to '.xls'.